# How to get type of the module in F#

Tags: reflection, f#

How to get 'System.Type' of the module?

For example module:

```
module Foo =
     let bar = 1
```

And this does not work:

```
printfn "%s" typeof<Foo>.Name
```

Error is:

```
The type 'Foo' is not defined
```

Comment: Being inquisitive here. Why would you need to do this? You know the name of the module, Foo, and I don't think F# has the ability to pass modules as value. Thanks.

Comment: The need is simple, I need some automation. I can do this with reflection. PowerPack.Metadata allows to iterate through modules, but may be there is something more easy.

Comment: I need to do this also for an strongly typed API to a library I'm writing.

Comment: Cross reference: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2916294)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would certainly be nice to have a `moduleof` operator...  Since there's not one, the easiest way to do what you want is probably to use the Metadata library in the F# PowerPack:

```
#r "FSharp.PowerPack.Metadata.dll" 
open Microsoft.FSharp.Metadata

// get .NET assembly by filename or other means
let asm = ...

let fasm = FSharpAssembly.FromAssembly asm
let t = fasm.GetEntity("Foo").ReflectionType
```

Unfortunately, this won't work with dynamic assemblies (such as those generated via F# Interactive).  You can do something similar using vanilla `System.Reflection` calls, but that's more dependent on having a good understanding of the compiled form that your module takes.

Comment: Main problem is that 'FSharpAssembly.FromAssembly asm' loads all types. Also reduce type safety.

Comment: @Mike - I'm not sure what you mean by "reduce type safety"...  There is no way to use a module as a generic type parameter, so you will have to use a string.  This is unfortunate, but unavoidable.

Comment: does this still require a power pack to do or is there a better way 5 years later?

Comment: Or 7 years later still

Answer (score 40):

You could add a marker type to the module and then discover the module's type from that:

```
module Foo =  
    type internal Marker = interface end
    let t = typeof<Marker>.DeclaringType
```

Answer (score 6):

It can also be done using [Quotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233212.aspx). First, define this helper function somewhere:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns

let getModuleType = function
| PropertyGet (_, propertyInfo, _) -> propertyInfo.DeclaringType
| _ -> failwith "Expression is no property."
```

Then, you can define a module and get its type like this:

```
module SomeName =
    let rec private moduleType = getModuleType <@ moduleType @>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does for me, although I modified the second part to: `module SomeName = let rec moduleType = getModuleType <@ moduleType @>;;`, then `SomeName.moduleType;;` should output the type information.

Answer (score -2):

module name is not a type.

`List` in `List.map` and `let (a:List<int>) = [1;2;3]` are different.

The first `List` is a module name, the second is a type.

Comment: I am concerned about 'FSharpType.IsModule(System.Type)', so module IS type, at least in CLR terms.

Comment: The name of the static class (type) that the `List` module is compiled to is probably `ListModule`.