# F# WPF: Handling click events in ListBox

Tags: wpf, f#, fsharp.viewmodule

I'm trying to create a simple task scheduler using F# and WPF. It's basically just a list of tasks where every task has a 'Delete' button. Handling button clicks outside of the list is not a problem -- this can be handled with a regular command. However handling a button click **in** the list item is not straightforward. I tried using RelayCommand described [here](https://sergeytihon.wordpress.com/2013/04/27/wpf-mvvm-with-xaml-type-provider/) with binding routed to parent, but the sender object is always null (I expected it to be the task object from the collection). Also tried attaching a property as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38817055/656860), but couldn't make it work.

How do I assign an event handler that obtains the task object with clicked Delete button?

Here is the App.fs:

```
namespace ToDoApp

open System
open System.Windows
open System.Collections.ObjectModel
open System.Windows.Input
open FSharp.ViewModule
open FSharp.ViewModule.Validation
open FsXaml

type App = XAML<"App.xaml">
type MainView = XAML<"MainWindow.xaml">

type Task(str) = 
    member x.Description with get() = str

type MainViewModel() as self = 
    inherit ViewModelBase()  

    let tasks = new ObservableCollection<Task>()

    let addTaskCommand() =
        let descr = sprintf "Do something at %A" (DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30.0))
        tasks.Add <| new Task(descr)

    member this.Tasks with get() = tasks
    member this.AddTask = this.Factory.CommandSync addTaskCommand

module main =
    [<STAThread>]
    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv =
        App().Run()
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```xml
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ToDoApp;assembly=ToDoApp"
    xmlns:fsxaml="http://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml"
    Title="Simple ToDo app" Height="200" Width="400">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Name="newJobButton" Command="{Binding AddTask}" Width="100" Height="32" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5" HorizontalAlignment="Left">New task</Button>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ListBox Name="lstBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Description}" Margin="5 5 0 0"/>
                            <!-- OnClick ??? -->
                            <Button Grid.Column="1">Delete</Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

App.xaml is trivial, so I'm not showing it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to stick to Commands:

**ViewModel**

```
member __.DelTask = 
    __.Factory.CommandSyncParam 
        (fun task -> tasks.Remove task |> ignore)
```

**XAML**

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" 
        Command="{Binding DataContext.DelTask, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
        >Delete</Button>
```

Using event handlers in XAML results in spaghetti code which is harder to test and maintain (i.e. separation of concerns, handling business logic problems separately from UI problems).

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!