# How to get the AST of functions in a [<ReflectedDefinition>] tagged module?

Tags: f#

```
[<ReflectedDefinition>]
module Foo = 
    let x = 5
    let y () = 6
    let z a = a
```

I tried to find out how to get the AST in this situation a couple of times now and keep failing. Time to ask the question here.

So far, I thought that a module would be mappped to a class with static members internally and as such, it should be the equivalent of:

```
[<ReflectedDefinition>] 
type Foo =
    static member x = 5
    static member y () = 6
    static member z a = a

let bar_members = 
    typeof<Bar>.GetMethods()
    |> Array.filter (fun mi -> match mi with | MethodWithReflectedDefinition x -> true | _ -> false)
    |> Array.map (fun m -> sprintf "%s: %A" (m.Name) (Expr.TryGetReflectedDefinition(m :> MethodBase) ) )
```

In the latter case, I could use `typeof<Foo>.GetMembers()` (or `GetMethods()`?!), cast it to `Reflection.MethodBase` and use this as an argument for `Expr.TryGetReflectedDefinition()`.

But unfortunately, this is not working with the module version.

So, how to do it?

If you want to play with the code, you might want to open some namespaces:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.DerivedPatterns
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection
open System.Reflection
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes go down to actually getting the type of the Module.  In order to do that, there's a great answer here by Phillip Trelford: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14706890/5438433

Basically, you add a helper value to your module which returns the type of that module:

```
[<ReflectedDefinition>]
module Foo = 
    type internal IMarker = interface end
    let fooType = typeof<IMarker>.DeclaringType

    let x = 5
    let y () = 6
    let z a = a
```

You can then use `fooType` to retrieve the reflected definitions.

```
 let foo_members = 
     Foo.fooType.GetMethods()
     |> Array.filter (fun mi -> match mi with | MethodWithReflectedDefinition x -> true | _ -> false)
     |> Array.map (fun m -> sprintf "%s: %A" (m.Name) (Expr.TryGetReflectedDefinition(m :> MethodBase) ) )
```

I can then, e.g. print the results:

> [|"get_fooType: Some PropertyGet (Some (Call (None, TypeOf, [])), DeclaringType, [])";
>   "get_x: Some Value (5)"; 
>   "y: Some Lambda (unitVar0, Value (6))";
>   "z: Some Lambda (a, a)"|]

Comment: I saw this question. And I tried the answer using a ``GetModuleType`` helper function. I tried in interactive and it did not work. I think your answer is roughly the same. Is there a way without powerpack (which should be obsolete by now) and which works in interactive, as well? And also which works without adding tags or alike to the module? I remember I asked in some other forum about it and never got an answer. Why is there not some ``Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.Module.GetType()`` or alike?

Comment: @BitTickler It's only the first answer to that question that requires powerpack.  The example code I posted there works fine in interactive.

Comment: Indeed - just replicated and it works! Well - I will use this as a workaround until some Microsoft guys decide there should be a straightforward way to do it! My thanks!

Comment: @BitTickler I had a quick look on the F# language design user voice site and it doesn't seem this has been brought up there before, could be worth listing it there?  https://fslang.uservoice.com/

Comment: I stumbled across this while thinking about ways to (meta) program applications which require different languages to cooperate. Example: SecondLife scripting language and http with script for some SecondLife AJAX based HUD. Or: Some f# backend for some websocket html application. More esoteric: Program C in F#, test it in F#, then generate code from it, hopefully with fewer bugs. Anytime I think about such things, I stumble across the problem on how to use [<ReflectedDefinition>] on a module. Corner case or useful to the public? You decide ;)

Answer (score 0):

For the use case, when the reflected definitions are in another assembly (like an F# dll, for example), you can do without the marker interface trick, as shown below:

```
open System
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.DerivedPatterns
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection
open System.Reflection
open FSharp.Reflection.FSharpReflectionExtensions

let tryGetReflectedModules (a : Assembly) : seq<TypeInfo>  = 
    a.DefinedTypes 
    |> Seq.filter 
        (fun dt -> 
            dt.CustomAttributes
            |> Seq.map (fun cad -> cad.AttributeType)
            |> Seq.filter ((=) (typeof<ReflectedDefinitionAttribute>))
            |> Seq.isEmpty
            |> not
        )

let astFromReflectedDefinition (mi : MethodInfo) : Expr option =
    mi :> MethodBase |> Expr.TryGetReflectedDefinition

let reflectedMethodsOfAModule (m : System.Type) : (MethodInfo * Expr) [] =
    m.GetMethods()
    |> Array.map (fun m -> (m,astFromReflectedDefinition m))
    |> Array.filter (snd >> Option.isSome)
    |> Array.map (fun (x,y) -> (x, Option.get y))

let reflectAssembly (assemblyPath : string) =
    let a = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath) 
    a 
    |> tryGetReflectedModules
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> (x,reflectedMethodsOfAModule (x.AsType())))
```

Where, for example, the assembly I used for testing the code above looked like this:

```
namespace Input

[<ReflectedDefinition>]
module Api =
    let trace s = 
        for _ in [0..3] do System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine s

[<ReflectedDefinition>]
module Foo =
    let foobar (x : string) : string =
        x.ToUpper()
```

You get the top level types in the assembly, which just so happen to be the (static) classes, representing the modules of the Fsharp assembly and test for the `ReflectedDefinitionAttribute` presence. Then, you take it from there.