# FSharp Reflection in fsx script - does the module define a variable of name foo?

Tags: reflection, f#, f#-scripting

If I have a module of name `MyModule` defined in an .fsx script and referenced from within another .fsx script; is it possible to determine at runtime if the module defines a variable `foo`?

I am trying to implement something like this:

```
let fooWithDefault = 
    let cfgType:Type = typedefof<MyModule>
    let propOpt = 
        cfgType.GetProperties()
        |> Seq.tryFind( fun p -> p.Name = "foo")

    match propOpt with
    | Some foo -> foo.GetValue(null).ToString()
    | None -> "My Default Value for f"
```

The above attempt fails with the error:

> The type 'MyModule' is not defined

Comment: I think there will be two problems with this, MyModule should be a class, not a module (which is probably not a type), and in an fsx file FSI will prepend an artifical namespace if you use #load. If you use a class in a dll or an .fs file, it might work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a module would compile to a type: The docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/modules suggest "It is implemented as a common language runtime (CLR) class that has only static members." Don't know about how FSI deals with it though. Any way to know or determine which artificial namespace it prepends?

Comment: It certainly does compile to a type but actually getting a module's type requires some shenanigans.  This answer shows the usual way of doing that if you really need to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14706890/5438433

Comment: Thanks folks - Having given it a bit more thought, I can work around it with `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes() |> Seq.find (fun t -> t.Name = "MyModule")` - risk of a name collision is negligible and there are no perf worries in my use case

Comment: you're correct that a module is like a static class for CLR purposes. If you run/load the code that creates the type you'll see somethinge like: `namespace FSI_0005` prepended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible (somewhat kludgy) approach is to enumerate all the types in the executing assembly:

```
let fooWithDefault = 
    let cfgType = 
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        |> Seq.find(fun t -> t.Name = "MyModule")

    let propOpt = 
        cfgType.GetProperties()
        |> Seq.tryFind( fun p -> p.Name = "foo")

    match propOpt with
    | Some foo -> foo.GetValue(null).ToString()
    | None -> "My Default Value for f"
```

If using this approach we'd need to be aware that there is a risk of a name collision if we have 2 entities named 'MyModule'. Also, enumerating all the types in the executing assembly is surely sub-optimal.

With that said it seems to work ok for the limited test-cases I have attempted