# Get type of a module at compile time in F#

Tags: f#, compile-time-constant

We know that in C# we can get type of a type at compile time using `typeof(OutType)` this lets us pass this to attributes later as it is constant expression.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297236/how-to-get-type-of-the-module-in-f) question, but it doesn't really address the compile time usage.

So my question is: Is there a way to get `System.Type` of a given module at compile type within F# standard library?

Comment: Why are you trying to do that specifically? I understand the part why you need a compile time constant, but I don't understand what would you do once you got hold of the module's runtime type.

Comment: I my case I need it to supply it to NUnit’s TestCaseSource attribute overload

Comment: Can I obtain its type at compile time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F# disallows obtaining a module's type using its `typeof` operator by design, as they're not first-class concepts in the language.

From the [spec](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf), section 13.2:

> F# modules are compiled to provide a corresponding compiled CLI type declaration and
>   System.Type object, although the System.Type object is not accessible by using the typeof
>   operator.

Modules compile to static classes however, so it is possible to obtain the type at runtime using reflection (and that's what happens in `typeof<MyModule.Dummy>.DeclaringType` example), and it's possible to obtain the type of a module defined in a referenced F# assembly using `typeof`operator in C#.

For what you're trying to do, you'd best use a class instead of a module, because then you can get hold of the type without hassle:

```
type MyFactoryClass = 
    static member TestCases = [ 1; 2; 3 ]

...

[<Test; TestCaseSource(typeof<MyFactoryClass>, "TestCases">] 
let test (arg: int) = ...
```

Comment: I know I can do it like that, thats ehy I never insisted in my answer about my specific case but rather if there is 1:1 equivalent in F# to C#’s typeof

Comment: Thanks mate, this usage of `TestCaseSource` succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK to refer to a type inside that module (or create a dummy one if there are no types), you could do this:

```
module MyModule =
    type Dummy = Dummy

let myModule = typeof<MyModule.Dummy>.DeclaringType
```

Comment: Usage of `.DeclaringType` means that's not a compile time constant however (that is, you can't use that as an argument to an attribute constructor).